# 304 status code appears in all paths except root path in Node Express app

Tags: node.js, express

I used Express to write the CRUD API for the MVC pattern.

And there was a problem applying the template to the CRUD API.

I am using the index view as root path. However, the same view is displayed regardless of the link in the index view. I get `304 status code` for all accesses other than root path.

Can someone help me out for finding the source of this issue.

**app.js**

```
...
const post = require("./routes/post");
app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});
app.use("/posts", post);
...
```

**index.pug**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
  body
    a(href='/posts/new') new
```

**routes**

```
const postsController = require("../controller/posts_controller");
router.get("/new", postsController.post_new);
```

**controller**

```
exports.post_new = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("new");
};
```

Comment: Try moving `app.use("/"...)` below all the other routes. I'm not 100% sure but I think express route processing treat "/" as "default route"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express checks routes in the order that they're defined in and uses the first handler whose route matches the path of the incoming request. Since you put your root route (`"/"`) at the top, and all routes match the root route (at least), it will match and handle any request that comes in.

To fix this you can move the definition of your root route to the end of app.js. For example:

```
const post = require("./routes/post");
app.use("/posts", post);
app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});
```

In general you should define sub-routes before their parents and define routes with static values before those with variables in the same positions. So a good example order would be:

```
app.use("/posts/new", ...);
app.use("/posts/:id", ...);
app.use("/posts", ...);
app.use("/", ...);
```

Comment: For me the node is too hard. Answer Thank you very much. Is there another protocol to keep the code order like this?

Comment: @yosen I'd say break your routing code into separate files using routers (which it looks like you are doing) and then it's easier to check that the top-level routes are in the correct order (usually only the index/root route would be a problem). Then in each separate file be consistent about the order of your routes that follows this sort of scheme. That way it'll be easier to make sure your routes are working properly. Also set up automated tests if you can.